# Google Re-Captcha is not validating

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I have got a working contact form with PHP form processing and I have added Google recapture, however. The recapture is not validating And when the form is submitted, then the user receives the following error:

This page isn’t working www.example.co.uk is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

My code is as follow:

HTML

```
<div class="contact">

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Contact US</h2>
        <div class="contact-form">

            <div class="col-md-8 contact-grid">
                <form id="test" action="form-process.php" method="POST">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='name';}" required>
                    <br>
                    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='email';}" required>
                    <br>
                    <select id="contact" name="dropdown" onchange="handleOption(this)" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Crew/Gang</option>
                        <option value="NC Maphia">NC Maphia</option>
                        <option value="deadeye/index">Dead Eye</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <select id="contact" name="dropdown2" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Gang</option>
                        <option value="Grand Theft Auto V">Grand Theft Auto V</option>
                        <option value="Red Dead Redemption II">Red Dead Redemption II</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <select id="contact" name="dropdown3" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Platform</option>
                        <option value="Xbox One">Xbox One</option>
                        <option value="PS4">PS4</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <select id="contact" name="dropdown4" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Reason For Contacting Us</option>
                        <option value="Joining NC Maphia">Joining NC Maphia</option>
                        <option value="Recruitment Requirments">Recruitment Requirments</option>
                        <option value="Events">Events</option>
                        <option value="Report A Member">Report A Member</option>
                        <option value="Webmaster">Webmaster</option>
                        <option value="General Inquiry">General Inquiry</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='subject';}">
                    <br>
                    <textarea name="message" cols="77" rows="6" placeholder="Message" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'message';}" required></textarea>
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Site-Key-Here"></div>
                    <div class="send">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" >
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) //If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):
        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'My-Key-Here';
        //get verify response data
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->success):
{
$notification="";  //Used for catching all your messages
//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$errors = [];

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dropdown = $_POST['dropdown'];
$dropdown2 = $_POST['dropdown2'];
$dropdown3 = $_POST['dropdown3'];
$dropdown4 = $_POST['dropdown4'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
if ($_POST) $post=1;
//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, 
//you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
if (!$dropdown) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter which crew/gang you are attempting to contact.'; 
if (!$dropdown2) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter which game you are referring too.'; 
if (!$dropdown3) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter which platform you are  currentlyplaying on.'; 
if (!$dropdown4) $errors[count($errors)] = 'We need too know the reason for your message.';
if (!$message) $errors[count($errors)] = 'We need more detail on why you are contacting us.'; 
//if the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {
//recipient - change this to your name and email
$to = 'no_reply@ncmaphia.co.uk';    
//sender
$from = $email;

//subject and the html message
$subject = 'Hello from ' . $name;    
$message = '
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
<p>You have recieved a message from $name using your contact form at www.ncmaphia.co.uk
<table>
    <tr><td>Name: </td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email: </td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Crew/Gang: </td><td>' . $dropdown . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Game: </td><td>' . $dropdown2 . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Platform: </td><td>' . $dropdown3 . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Reason For Contacting Us: </td><td>' . $dropdown4 . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Subject: </td><td>' . $subject . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Message: </td><td>' . $message . '</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';
//send the mail
$result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

//if POST was used, display the message straight away
if ($_POST) {
    if ($result) header('location: thank-you.html', true, 303);
    else:
        $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
    endif;
    else:
        $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
    endif;
else:
    $errMsg = '';
    $succMsg = '';
endif;

//else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
//ajax script can react accordingly
//1 means success, 0 means failed
} else {
    $notification.= $result;    
}
//if the errors array has values
} else {
//display the errors message
for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br/>';
$notification.= '<a href="contact.html">Back</a>';
exit;
}
//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if ($result) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
} //First If loop
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: since the 500 is from your site, how is it a  Google recapture issue?

Comment: @tim Because the form submit perfectly, but once I add the recapture. That is when i receive the error.